# photoshop: change swatch color, and have all properties (text-color, layer-effects) using that swatch-color update as well

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I use Photoshop for designing websites. Doing that I always make use of swatches for text-color, begin/end points in gradients, strokes, etc. (through non-destructive layer-effects mostly)

I've often wondered if there's an approach to update a swatch color in Photoshop and have all object-properties update (backgrounds, strokes, etc. ) to which the former swatch-color was applied.  I'm talking here about the **reversible / non-destructive** properties such as text-color, layer-effects etc.

This would be a tremendous time-saver. (comparable to using color-variables in Less/sass instead of having to manually alter every property in vanilla css)